# SQL Select with If statement to assign values

Tags: sql

I have a multiple SELECT and trying to add If or Case statement to assign values based on what it is DB. Trying to change Y to DD and blanks to TTTT

My code looks like that

```
SELECT 
    wo_1.ata_chapter AS 1,
    wo_2.type AS 2,
    wo_3.comp_partno AS 3,
    ' ' AS 4,
    wo_5.mel_code AS 5,
    WHEN wo_6.hil AS DD


FROM wo_db
```

I tried CASE

```
CASE 
    WHEN wo_6.hil = 'Y'
    Then 'DD'
    Else 'TTTT'
```

I tried If as well

```
IF (wo_6.hil = 'Y', 'DD', Then 'TTTT')
```

Comment: Your `case` _expression_ needs an `end` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for `case` would be:

```
(CASE WHEN wo_6.hil = 'Y' THEN 'DD' ELSE 'TTTT' END) as xx
```

The parentheses are not needed (although recommend them), but the `END` is.

Note:  This is based on your code.  Your description doesn't specify what to do when the value is neither `'Y'` nor blanks.